# Access SQL Server from remote location

Tags: remote-access, sql-server-2008-r2

I have remote access enabled in SQL Server at my work network, which is on my "server". In the office, I have my desktop machine which I can use SQL Server Management Studio to access - no problems. I can use telnet [LOCAL_IP] 1433 with no problems.

When I am at home, I want to access the SQL Server too. I can PING [EXTERNAL_IP] address to the office fine (which is a router), but can't telnet [EXTERNAL_IP] 1433. So my machine can't access it when using SQL Server Management Studio.

I thought it was a router firewall issue, I have modified the router firewall to let my IP address through on TCP and UDP on ports 1433 and 1434 both source and destination. I've also tried letting my home IP through on all ports too, and still nothing. I've also tried to disable the firewall on the windows server at work.

I can set up RDP fine though....so I am thinking something I don't know about in SQL Server is the problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions to try please?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). In short, you need to configure your router to redirect traffic to 1433 to the SQL Server.

This is a HUGE security issue, obviously, since you're exposing a server directly to the internet. I'd recommend setting up some sort of VPN functionality instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Extra question, if I block all connections to port 1433 other than my home IP, then surely it's secure then?

Comment: @StuartPalmer: A "whitelist"...It's better. The problem becomes more about it being a sort of oddball hole in the firewall: not insecure, but unexpected. Is your home IP address static?

Comment: no, my IP at home dynamic, so from home have to go into firewall settings and change my allowed IP through.